# Determining linear independency among lags of a vector for example between x(n-1) and x(n-2) using least square fitting methods

Tags: matlab, regression, curve-fitting, least-squares

I need to find the linear independence using x(n-1) to fit x(n-2) using least square method and calculating the error between x(n-2) and the estimated vector. This is my code to find lags of the X(n) and performing the fitting algoritm.

```
PPG = load('P.txt')
Pini = 10;
N = length(PPG);
M = zeros(N-Pini,Pini);
for i = 1:Pini
M(:,i) = PPG(Pini-i+1:end-i,1); % each column is a candidate vector
end
for i = 1:Pini
j = i;
while j < Pini+1
    [curve, goodness, output] = fit(M(:,i),M(:,j),'poly1');
    G(i,j) = goodness.rmse;
    R(i,j) = goodness.rsquare;
    Coeff1(i,j) = curve.p1;
    Coeff2(i,j) = curve.p2;
    %Coeff3(1,i) = curve.p3;
    %yfit(i,:) = Coeff3(1,i) + Coeff2(1,i)*M(:,1) + Coeff1(1,i)*M(:,1).^2;
    yfit(i,:) = Coeff2(i,j) + Coeff1(i,j)*M(:,i);
    Error(i,:) = M(:,j)' - yfit(i,:);
    MeanError(i,j) = mean(abs(Error(i,:)));
    j = j+1;                                        
end
end
```

But my rmse does not seem to give a correct answer because it just decrease when the second vector's lag get close to the first vector's. I cannot find where I did wrong.

Comment: Can you share p.txt?

Comment: Ii can be found at " http://www.physionet.org/atm/mimic2wdb/36/3600039/3600039/PLETH/0/3600/export/matlab/3600039m.mat"

Comment: Gives me an error - file not found

Comment: http://www.physionet.org/atm/mimic2wdb/36/3600039/3600039/PLETH/0/3600/export/matlab/3600039m.mat                                                          yes you are right, but I checked it again. I can access by this link. is there any where that i can upload the file?